# frm-41084 Error getting Group Cell

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I changed the record group from

```
                select profile, profile 
            from profiles 
            where profile_type = 'UC' 
            and active = 'Y' 
            order by profile_attribute2

              to

            select profile, profile 
            from dss.v_unit_conditions
            where div_no = to_number(:global.g_div_no)
            and profile_type = 'UC' 
            and active = 'Y'
```

When I compile forms I am getting this error.

> *frm-41084 Error getting Group Cell.*

Help appreciated.

Comment: it seems, there should exist an ambiguous definition problem for `select profile, profile from ...`

Comment: Does your new query runs correctly in SQL*Plus? Do you have access to `DSS.V_UNIT_CONDITIONS`? Can `global.g_div_no` be converted to a number (i.e. can it contain characters different from digits)?

Comment: What is the data type of `div_no` in table `dss.v_unit_conditions`? It should be `number` since you compare it to a number; if it isn't, perhaps that's the issue. Then: what (data type) is `:global.g_div_no`? if it is not a number, why not? If it **is** a number, why do you need to put it within `to_number(...)`?

Comment: @mathguy, global variables in Forms are *always* strings, i.e. VARCHAR2(255), that's just how it is; you can't change their datatype.